# Перенос полосы прокрутки в верхнюю часть

Tags: javascript, css

Как перенести горизонтальную полосу прокрутки в верхнюю часть страницы? CSS или JS.

Спасибо!

Comment: Вы имеете в виду горизонтальную полосу прокрутки?

Comment: Да, горизонтальную, сейчас исправлю вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для симуляции второго горизонтального скроллбара наверху элемента надо расположить над элементом с полосой прокрутки еще один "фейковый" `div` с высотой, достаточной для полосы прокрутки. А затем приписать `handlers`  события `scroll` обоим элементам, чтобы их синхронизировать при прокрутке.

Если надо убрать нижний скроллбар, просто пишем в его свойствах `overflow:hidden` (в данном случае это `wrapper2`).

```js
$(function() {
  $(".wrapper1").scroll(function() {
    $(".wrapper2").scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
  });
  $(".wrapper2").scroll(function() {
    $(".wrapper1").scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper1,
.wrapper2 {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.wrapper1 {
  height: 20px;
}

.wrapper2 {
  height: 200px;
}

.div1 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 20px;
}

.div2 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #88FF88;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="div1"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="div2">
    <!-- Content Here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/1/</sub>